# Saving information in EditText in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to retain the data in my Edittext views, using onsaveinstancestate. The user clicks on the "add" button, which is supposed to retain the information in the Edittext views. When the add button is clicked, the user is taken back to activity main. When the module is selected for editing, the edit_module layout is shown but without the information in the edittext views, which I am trying to retain. Any ideas?? I think I may be missing  a step, is there more to it than saving the strings in the onsaveinstancestate method, and then assigning those strings to the Edittext views when the activity is called?? New to Android.

NewModule.java

```
public class NewModule extends Activity{

// The EditText objects

EditText ModuleCode;
EditText ModuleName;
EditText ModuleType;
EditText DayOfWeek;
EditText StartTime;
EditText EndTime;
EditText Location;
EditText AdditionalInfo;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      // Get saved data if there is any

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbTools = new DBTools(this);
    // Designate that add_module.xml is the interface used

    setContentView(R.layout.add_module);

    // Initialize the EditText objects
    ModuleCode= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modcodeet);
    ModuleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modnameet);
    ModuleType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moduletypeet);
    DayOfWeek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dowet);
    StartTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starttimeet);
    EndTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endtimeet);
    Location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationet);
    AdditionalInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.additionalinfoet);



}
public void addNewModule(View view) {

    // Will hold the HashMap of values 

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new  HashMap<String, String>();




    // Get the values from the EditText boxes

    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleCode", ModuleCode.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleName", ModuleName.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleType", ModuleType.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("DayOfWeek", DayOfWeek.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("StartTime", StartTime.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("EndTime", EndTime.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("Location", Location.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("AdditionalInfo", AdditionalInfo.getText().toString());

    // Call for the HashMap to be added to the database

    dbTools.insertModule(queryValuesMap);

    // Call for MainActivity to execute

    this.callMainActivity(view);


}
public void callMainActivity(View view) {
    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(theIntent);
}   

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){


EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modcodeet);
String code = editText.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("code", code);


EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modnameet);
String name = editText2.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("name", name);

EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moduletypeet);
String type = editText3.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("type", type);


EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dowet);
String dow = editText4.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("dow", dow);

EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starttimeet);
String messagesubject = editText5.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("start", messagesubject);

EditText editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endtimeet);
String end = editText6.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("end",end);

EditText editText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationet);
String location = editText7.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("location", location);

 EditText editText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.additionalinfoet);
String additionalinfo = editText8.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("additionalinfo", additionalinfo);

super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}

}
```

TIA

Edit Module.java

```
public class EditModule extends Activity{



EditText ModuleCode;
EditText ModuleName;
EditText ModuleType;
EditText DayOfWeek;
EditText StartTime;
EditText EndTime;
EditText Location;
EditText AdditionalInfo;

DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_module);


    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
          String strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("code"); 
          if (strValue != null);
           ModuleCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.modcodeet);
          ModuleCode.setText(strValue); 

        strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
          if (strValue != null);
          ModuleName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.modnameet);  
          ModuleName.setText(strValue);

          strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("type");
        if(strValue != null);
        ModuleType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.moduletypeet);
            ModuleType.setText(strValue);

            strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("dow");
        if(strValue != null);
        DayOfWeek = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dowet);
        DayOfWeek.setText(strValue);

        strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("start");
        if (strValue != null);
        StartTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.starttimeet);
        StartTime.setText(strValue);

        strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("end");
        if (strValue != null);
        EndTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.endtimeet);
        EndTime.setText(strValue);

        strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("location");
        if (strValue != null);
        Location = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locationet);
        Location.setText(strValue);

        strValue = savedInstanceState.getString("additionalinfo");
        if (strValue != null);
        AdditionalInfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.additionalinfoet);
        AdditionalInfo.setText(strValue);

    }




public void editModule(View view){

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();



    ModuleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modnameet);
    ModuleType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moduletypeet);
    DayOfWeek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dowet);
    StartTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starttimeet);
    EndTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endtimeet);
    Location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationet);
    AdditionalInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.additionalinfoet);



    this.callMainActivity(view);

}


public void callMainActivity(View view){

    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);

    startActivity(objIntent);

}



}
```

Comment: do u want to pass edittext data to next activity???

Comment: Its not the very next activity, it goes from the add_module activity to the activity_main to the edit_module activity.I want the information in the add_module edittet fields to be shown in the edit_moule edittext fields, but it does not go directly from add_module to edit_module, if that makes sense, so I'm not sure that getting the extras from the previous activity would work.

Comment: Store them in static String variables in your add_module. In edit_modules access it via class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
//intialization of shared preferences
private SharedPreferences preferences;

//in oncreate() give like this:
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// store the edittext value in shared preferences
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("edittextvalue", edittextvalue);
edit.commit();

//whereever u want to get value and use
String apptext = preferences.getString("edittextvalue","");
```

Answer (score 1):

use SharedPreferences to save edittext value